# How do i skip null string during file reading?

Tags: java

Example:

```
Java is a set of several computer software
and specifications developed by Sun Microsystems,
("PROBLEM HOW DO I SKIP THIS SPACE BELOW?") 

later acquired by Oracle Corporation, that provides
a system for developing application software and
deploying it in a cross-platform computing environment.
```

I want to know how, using Java, you would ignore the blank lines in the iput file.

Comment: Ok. What is the question now?

Comment: Adjusted question to what I _think_ you were trying to ask. Please check and confirm/deny in a comment.

Comment: yes this is my question @paxdiablo

Answer (score 4):

It’s pseudo-code time! \o/

```
while (file is not read completely) {
    line = read a line from file;
    if (line is empty) {
        continue; // skip this line!
    }
    process line;
}
```